# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: c++, pointers, dll

I am working on some implementation of brute force algorithm and this seems like a basic question but I can't make it work.

Following line of code breaks program:

```
found[next] = j;
```

Declaration of array:

```
int* found = new int[30];
```

j is counter that is increasing in for-loop. Code like found[0] = 0 works OK. If I use variables for index and value it crashes. Error in Visual Studio 2012 is "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt".

I use int* becouse it's in c++ dll that I use with c# application.

Comment: Where is `next` coming from? Is it greater than `29`?

Comment: Don't use magic numbers like "`30`". Instead, express your containers in terms of logical depedencies of values, and refer to those values abstractly. Then silly mistakes like this are far less likely.

Comment: No, it's less than 30. In fact, it's 0.

Comment: @drive235 Please show us more of your code. Everything from the declaration of `found` and including the `for` loop.

Comment: The error is an indication that EITHER `found` or `next` or both are "wrong" [or possibly `j`]. This could be an indication that SOMETHING ELSE is overwriting something that you rely on, such as `found` or `next`. The only way to really tell that is by looking at the code.

Comment: A simple check like `if (next < 30) found[next] = j; else std::cout << "Wow, next is " << next << std::endl;` should give a hint.

Comment: This code is probably not the code causing the problem, since it's effectively a  no-op (the inner loop says that always `i < m` while the if then requires `i >= m`)

Comment: I've edited my post. But now it seems that if condition breaks it since it opens file with breakpoint at static int __CLRCALL_OR_CDECL compare(const _Elem *_First1, const _Elem *_First2,size_t _Count).

Answer (score 0):

You need to control the value of next. Most probably, it is going out of bounds of your array